# Target a parent of evt.target

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have added a listener to container A, I add elements to container A dynamically which I want to drag around the stage. I have container B inside container A which contains bmp1, I also have bmp2. when I use evt.target in both cases it targets the bmp's. In the case of bmp1 how would I target container B instead? Eventually all the bmp's will be wrapped in a container once I get it working, bmp2 is for illustration purposes.

```
 myFunction:function(evt){ 
 pt = containerA.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY) 
 evt.target.x = pt.x + (evt.target.getBounds().width/2); 
 evt.target.y = pt.y - (evt.target.getBounds().height/2); 
 stage.update(); 
 }
```

Thx.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the HTML and how you're binding the event. Also you could try `evt.target.parentNode`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to upload an image to illustrate but I don't have enough points. I am using canvas and createjs so there are no elements in the HTML yet.

Comment: This was a parenting issue, I had a container between the bitmap and container A which I have removed and it works perfectly now just using evt.target.parent. A Scoping issue that reminds me of as2 programming.

Comment: Check out the `on` method, added in 0.7.0 - which includes a scope parameter.